# Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A new car is purchased for $35000$ dollars.

During the next $10$ years, the rate of change in the value of the car is given by the differential equation $dx/dt = -kx$,  where $x$ is the value of the car after $t$ years and $k$ is constant.

After $10$ years, the car is expected to have a value of $8000$ dollars.

Find the value of the car when it is $3$ years old.

Comment: You'll get your question down-voted and closed if you don't share your attempts of solving this problem on your own.

Comment: how we go about doing this because there is no equation to star off with

Comment: i just did dx/dt = -kx = dx/-kx=dt , than intergrated both side and go( lnx +c) 1/-k = t

Comment: @AvneelDeo And what are the solutions to this equation?

Answer (score 2):

We have $x(0)=35000$ and $x(10)=8000$, the solution for the differential equation is $x(t)=C e^{-kt}$ for constants $k,C$ which we can find by using the two known points.

By $35000=x(0)=C$ and $8000=x(10)=35000 e^{-10k}$ so that $k=-\frac{1}{10}\log(\frac{8}{35})$, then you only have to substitute everything in $x(3)$.

Comment: k= 0.06409780573 know x(3) = 35000e^(-3 ( 0.06409780573) ) = 28877.2660677 = $ 28877.27 ...im i on right track

Comment: Be careful, here $\log = \log_e$, not $\log_{10}$ ;) so your $k$ is not correct (see my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1850660/250502) below)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to solve the differential equation: The car is depreciated each year by the same factor $\lambda=\left({8\over35}\right)^{1/10}\doteq0.862784$. The value of the car after three years is therefore
$\lambda^3\cdot35\,000=22\,478.85$ dollars.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$
\begin{cases}
x'+kx=0 \\
x(0)=35000\\
x(10)=8000\\
\end{cases}
$$

For this kind of differential equation, we [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Basic_features) that the solution can be written as

$$
\exists C, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, ~~~~~~x(t)=Ce^{-\alpha t}
$$

To find $C$ and $\alpha$ we'll need the additional information about $x$.

$$
\begin{array}
&&x(0) &= C & \text{(from expression above)}\\
&x(0) &= 35000 & \text{(problem data)}\\
\text{therefore } &C&=35000&
\end{array}
$$

And, writing the neperian logarithm as $\log$

$$
\begin{array}
&&x(10) &= 35000e^{-10\alpha} & \text{(from expression above)}\\
&x(10) &= 8000 & \text{(problem data)}\\
\text{therefore } &\alpha&=-\frac{\log\left(8/35\right)}{10}&
\end{array}
$$

So we have

$$
x(t) = 35000\exp\left(\frac{\log\left(8/35\right)~t}{10}\right)
$$

Finally

$$
x(3) \approx 22478
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\left.\begin{array}{rcccccl}
\ds{-k\int_{0}^{10}\dd t} & \ds{=} & \ds{-10k} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\int_{35000}^{8000}{\dd\mathrm{x} \over \mathrm{x}}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\ln\pars{8000 \over 35000}}
\\[3mm]
\ds{-k\int_{0}^{3}\dd t} & \ds{=} & \ds{-3k} & \ds{=} &\ds{\int_{35000}^{\mathrm{x}\pars{3}}{\dd\mathrm{x} \over \mathrm{x}}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\ln\pars{x\pars{3} \over 35000}}
\end{array}\right\rbrace
\\[5mm]
& \imp\ {-10k \over -3k} = {10 \over 3} =
-\,{\ln\pars{35/8} \over \ln\pars{\mathrm{x}\pars{3}/35000}}
\\[3mm] & \imp\
\color{#f00}{\mathrm{x}\pars{3}} =
\color{#f00}{35000\exp\pars{-\,{3 \over 10}\,\ln\pars{35 \over 8}}}
\approx 22478.88
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to solve:

$$x'(t)=-kx(t)\Longleftrightarrow\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}=-k\Longleftrightarrow\int\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}\space\text{d}t=\int-k\space\text{d}t\Longleftrightarrow\ln|x(t)|=\text{C}-kt$$

Now, you know that when $t=0$ the car is $35000$ dollars and when $t=10$ the car is $8000$ dollars, so:

$$
\begin{cases}
\ln|35000|=\text{C}-k\cdot0\\
\ln|8000|=\text{C}-k\cdot10
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
\ln(35000)=\text{C}\\
\ln(8000)=\text{C}-10k
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
\text{C}=\ln(35000)\\
\ln(8000)=\ln(35000)-10k
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
\text{C}=\ln(35000)\\
k=\frac{\ln(35000)-\ln(8000)}{10}
\end{cases}
$$

So, we get that:

$$\ln|x(t)|=\ln(35000)-\frac{t\left(\ln(35000)-\ln(8000)\right)}{10}$$

Now, find $x(t)$ when $t=3$:

$$\ln|x(3)|=\ln(35000)-\frac{3\left(\ln(35000)-\ln(8000)\right)}{10}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$|x(3)|=\exp\left[\ln(35000)-\frac{3\left(\ln(35000)-\ln(8000)\right)}{10}\right]$$

So, $x(3)$:

$$x(3)=35000^{1-\frac{3}{10}}\cdot8000^{\frac{3}{10}}\approx22478.87783812231$$